# Parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) if else

Tags: haskell

I have this code it's working, but it doesn't work when I add this statement:

```
do 

let r = ....
```

I get an error. The code:

```
paly :: Matrix -> String->Int -> Matrix
paly mat flag 10 =mat
paly mat flag i =do
                            let a=1
                            let b=2
                            .....
                            if a/=(-1) ||b/=(-1) then
                                if y==2 then
                                    take x mat ++
                                    [take x (mat !! y) ++ [flag] ++ drop (x + 1) (mat !! x)] ++
                                    drop (y + 1) mat
                                else if a==2 then
                                    take a mat ++
                                    [take a (mat !! y) ++ [flag] ++ drop (x + 1) (mat !! x)] ++
                                    drop (y + 1) mat
                                else if b==2 then
                                                    --do
                                                        --let r = posState mat
                                                        take b mat ++
                                                        [take x (mat !! y) ++ [flag] ++ drop (x + 1) (mat !! x)] ++
                                                        drop (y + 1) mat
                                else
                                    take c mat ++
                                    [take c (mat !! y) ++ [flag] ++ drop (x + 1) (mat !! x)] ++
                                    drop (y + 1) mat
                            else 
                                paly mat flag (i+1)
```

Comment: Yikes, there's got to be a neater way of writing that in Haskell. What does it do? The problem is possibly that your `let` should be lined up somewhere else. For a start, get rid of all those tabs and use spaces (and don't indent so far). Tabs are notoriously problematic because editors and compilers can think about them differently.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:haskell-platform] or [tag:haskell-pipes].

Comment: There is a lot going on with this code sample. You have `let a=1` and then `if a /= -1` which will always be true, because `a` is 1, unless you're shadowing the name somewhere. Furthermore, you don't tell us what error you get, or where you're adding the bit of code at the top of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a spacing issue, but rather than fix that, I will show you a cleaner way to write your nested ifs

```
case (a, b, y) of
    (-1, -1, _) -> something
    (2, _, 2) -> somethingElse
    (_, 2, 2) ->yetSomethingElse
    _ -> defaultThing
```

If you rewrite this way, it will be a lot easier to fix the code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understanding you,Where exactly should I place the code !!

Comment: Take the stuff in each if-then-else case, and place it in the appropriate case....  So, like `if cond then a else b` becomes- `case cond of True -> a; _ -> b`.  For one `if`, neither way is cleaner, but for nested `if`s, the latter is hugely superior (for one thing, there is no nesting).